# Initializing jQuery Noty Plugin shows green line

Tags: jquery, noty

[image: Here is screenshot of output.] I'm using jQuery Noty Plugin but notification is not shown properly. It is just shown as a line. It does not open with time. I have explored multiple options but could not achieve this. Here is sample code as well:

```
$.noty.defaults.killer = true;

noty({
   text: 'Happy!',
   layout: 'center',
   closeWith: ['click'],
   type: 'success'
});
```

I am using following dependencies:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/noty/jquery.promise.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/themes/relax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/noty/layouts/top.js"></script>
```

I have also used default settings but don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3xjfy.png

Comment: Please add a Plunker (https://plnkr.co/)  to your question.

Comment: Did you included jQuery before noty ?

Comment: The plugin appends notification elements to body. I suspect html is not structured properly or custom styles are overriding notification view.
Try functionality by removing custom css